# Does 「剣は 鋭 気は円」 make sense?

Tags: grammar

My father just obtained his 3rd kyu, and with it, a brown belt he's going to wear until he gets a black one. It's a tradition in our dojo to get a brown belt embroidered either with a Japanese saying or one's name. He chose the former and wanted to get a belt embroidered with 「剣は 鋭く気は円く」. However, as he does not speak Japanese, nor can he read hiragana, he mistook the 「く」for "line-ending-signs" and submitted the text to be embroidered without them. It'd be a lot of hassle and/or money to get it corrected; does the embroidering on the belt make sense as it is?

Comment: I am not a native speaker, but this looks a bit awkward to me since removing the く characters changes the grammar and hence the nuance of those two words. I think people who are familiar with the phrase in question would understand you are referring to that, however they would realize the く characters were omitted. Depending on how expensive it was, I'd consider redoing it.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, the altered one happens to make sense to me as a verse.

The original sentence reads "剣は鋭【するど】く 気は円【まる】く" using kun-yomi, but the altered one can be read as "剣は鋭【えい】 気は円【えん】" using on-yomi, which basically has the same meaning as the original one. It may not be very natural as ordinary Japanese prose, but it's similar to how people have to read [漢文](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanbun), so it looks convincing enough to me. I don't know it makes sense as a real classic Chinese sentence, though.

Note that you definitely need a small space (or comma) between 鋭 and 気, and no space elsewhere. Otherwise, it would look like one ungrammatical line including a strange word "鋭気".